# Synchronization using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I get the all [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data from the server using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests. But on my side I modified the data, so I need to send the modified data to the server using JavaScript, jQuery, [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap), [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and Ajax.

What would be some example of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url         : serverApiUrl,
    method      : "POST",
    scriptTag   : true,
    headers     : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    scope       : this,
    jsonData    : yourModifiedJsondata, 
    success     : successFN,
    failure     : failureFN
});

function onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   // Or use alerts if you can't see your log
   console.log("status: " + textStatus);
   console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
   // can't remember if this works:
   console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
}

console.log('ajaxing!'); 
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'post', 
   url: 'PRIVATE_URL', 
   data: {test:'asdf'}, 
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: function(data){ 
      console.log('done'); 
   },
   error: onError
});
```

Comment: Thanks,Is there any process to do the same requirement without using extjs.Because i am using phonegap.

Comment: Thanks you so much.Happy new year